# Can not change profile of sound card in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, soundcard, pavucontrol

I have a PC built on Asus Rog Rampage V Edition 10 running Ubuntu 16.04. This PC has 2 sound card modules with several outputs and inputs e.g. analogue stereo and digigal S/PDIF:

```
$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.usb-ASUS_SupremeFX_Hi-Fi-01.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I used to be on the built-in sound card and got sound outputs on front analogue-stereo connectors but no sound on SupremeFx_Hi-Fi. I tried to  make SupremeFx to work, followed some threads on-line but messed up with the on-board sound device. Now, I only have audio outputs at the graphic card HDMI ports.

I am now trying to bring everything back to normal. So, I removed every component related to sound system:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove alsa-base alsa-utils alsamixer
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove pulseaudio
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove pulseaudio-utils
$ rm -R ./.config/pulse/
```

reboot and reinstall them:

```
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Now, I've got an issue that the built-in audio is on `Digital Output(S/PDIF)` and I can not change by `pavucontrol`. To be more precise, I change the profile, but `pacmd list-cards` shows no device is available, also as soon as I change the output type by system audio settings, it returns to `Digital Output(S/PDIF)`. So far, no sound on the front stereo connector.

Appreciate any thought/help?

Comment: did you only reinstall 2 packages after uninstalling 5? suggest you install pavucontrol (Pulseaudio Volume Control) and try changing profile in there.
You probably want to disable hdmi audio from your video card, showing as device 0, so doesn't get used as default playback device?

Comment: Yes. I don't recall exactly, but have them all installed maybe through dependencies. I tried so but without success. I change the the device but the setting can't be saved.